# I'm having trouble installing Homestead on windows

Tags: php, laravel, installation, homestead

I need help. I've been struggling for the past couple of days and its a very frustrating process. I'm just getting started on coding and I cannot install homestead on my laptop. It's really frustrating because it feels like if I can't do this then maybe I shouldn't be coding. But I'm sure you all struggled. Hopefully you did as well.

Ok so I followed all of the steps on the laravel website. I think my problem is with the yaml file configuration.

When I try to vagrant up, this is what I'm getting:

> Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:
>
> There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
>   and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
>   an invalid or undefined variable.
>
> Path: C
>   Line number: 143
>   Message: undefined method `each'

This is how my Yaml file looks like.

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: c:/Users/ahmed/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    — c:/Users/ahmed/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: c:/Users/ahmed/Homestead
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/Homestead/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

I'm not sure where exactly I went wrong. But I'm pretty sure this is it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First: welcome to StackOverflow. Second: Although I can't help you with your problem, let me respond at this specific remark of yours: " if I can't do this then maybe I shouldn't be coding" : never, _ever_, *ever* say or think that again. It does not make you feel better about yourself. We are all learning and yes, frustration can be a part of it to the point that you might think you are not good enough. But that's not true. Keep believing in yourself and keep coding, no matter how little or small!

Comment: Just to understand your question better: are you using this guide? -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#first-steps